# prevent reloading of View with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I got a app with 2 view controllers. the first one contains a webview. when i navigate to the second view through an ibaction :

```
- (IBAction) showSecondView
{
    UIViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];   
}
```

and back to the first view:

```
    SecondViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
```

the first view is loading as on first time.
how can i prevent that the first view is reloading?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going back, you are just presenting an presenting the first view again. To go back to the previous view just dissmis the current presented viewController :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```